# Sort class member functions and variables in ascending order in header file

Tags: c++, vim

Given a class declaration thus:

```
class foo_{
public:
    int t1();
    const std::vector<int> & ureference(); 
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vecofpairs;
    string name;
}
```

I would like to sort the public functions in ascending order of their names. The following command in vim after appropriate visual selection of the lines:

`:'<,'>,!sort -k2`

sorts the functions thus:

```
const std::vector<int> & ureference(); 
int t1();
```

The `sort` sorts on the second column which in this case are `std::...` and `t1();`. Yet, this is not what I want. I want the sorting to be based on the column before the `(` on each line, so that the sorted order is:

```
int t1();
const std::vector<int> & ureference();
```

Likewise, I'd like to sort the member variables based on the column name immediately preceding `;` so that the sorted order is:

```
string name;
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vecofpairs;
```

Is there any appropriate vim shortcuts to achieve this? Or else, how can `sort` be used to sort based on field immediately prior to `(` or `;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Vim's built-in [`:sort`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asort) command to sort on arbitrary parts of the lines.

The built-in `:sort` can take a pattern, and then either skip that pattern or match that pattern to decide what to use as a key for sorting.

For example, in your case you can use `/.* /` as a pattern to skip everything until the last space on the line. (This requires that there's no trailing spaces after the `;`.)

To sort the methods:

```
:3,4sort /.* /
```

And the members:

```
:6,7sort /.* /
```

But perhaps this isn't exactly what you need. Say your methods have arguments (with spaces between them) and let's say you have a `&` or `*` next to the method name (`int *findmin(int *arr);` for example.)

Then you can match the method name with `/\k\S*(/`, that is a keyword character (so not `*` or `&`), followed by non-whitespace, followed by a literal `(`. You pass `:sort` a `r` flag to sort on the pattern match (not skip it), so:

```
:'<,'>sort /\k\S*(/ r
```

This last one is using Visual mode to select the block with the methods. When you press `:` from Visual mode, it will automatically fill in `:'<,'>` to use the range of lines from the Visual selection in the next command.

Vim regexes are really flexible, so you should be able to go very far with this setup as long as you're comfortable with them. I strongly recommend checking out `:help :sort`, which has some examples, and probaly read `:help pattern.txt` in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion. It works but it seems to sort with names of capitals on top. Please see https://imgur.com/a/xmbBhNZ for a screenshot.

Comment: `:sort` has an `i` flag to ignore case. `:%sort /\k\S*(/ ri`. Read `:help :sort`, there's a lot of good information there.

Comment: Yes, having ri did work. So, in case I would want to sort for members, in the regexp above, I should use ; in place of ( , I suppose. Also, I hope this matches the first occurence of ; and ( on the line. I would not want it to sort based on some // comment entry I have on the line. Thank you, once again. I will check the help sort.

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to map the regexps to a shortcut key into the .vimrc so that I can Visually select, hit : and then this shortcut to automatically fill in the regexp instead of having to type it out each time?

Comment: There are just so many ways to do that... `cnoremap` is one `q:` for Ex command history, Ctrl+R to read from a register... If that's something you do frequently, you can even create a function to do it (including selecting the appropriate lines in a class) and adding a user-command (see `:command`) using the proper regexes to sort methods, members, etc.